# ArrayList vs LinkedList efficiency

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I have a problem which uses many insertions in the list at the beginning and afterwards search and retrieval operations are extensively used, So which approach is good and efficient?

***Approach 1:*** Use `LinkedList` as my data structure for the whole program.

***Approach 2:*** Use `ArrayList` as my data structure for the whole program.

***Approach 3:*** Use `LinkedList` as my data structure at the beginning for insertion and do
 `Arraylist al = new Arraylist(ll);` 
for retrieval operations.

How much does the changing of data structure cost?? Is it actually worth doing it?

Comment: Converting a linklist to an arraylist is O(n). If it makes sense for your situation, it is completely reasonable to do. But unless you _know_ you have an efficiency problem, you could probably use an arraylist for the whole thing.

Comment: Generally, if a list is read from a lot of times, it is better to go for ArrayList as it provides random access. On the other hand, if elements are added into the List (at random locations) a lot of times, then it is better to go with LinkedList.

Comment: @khelwood What about `ArrayList`? It relies on `System.arraycopy`, which is a native method, so I suppose it should be faster and optimized?

Comment: @BackSlash Faster for what operations? Optimized for what?

Comment: @khelwood I don't know, that's why I'm asking. `LinkedList.toArray()` manually creates an array and fills it with all the nodes, while `ArrayList.toArray()` relies on a native method. Are native methods somehow faster or more optimized than plain java methods?

Comment: @BackSlash The elements in an ArrayList are already in an array, so it can use `arraycopy` to put them in a new array. The elements of a linked list are not already in an array, so `arraycopy` isn't applicable. I don't think that that the comparitive performance of `toArray` is what the question is about.

Comment: It's almost always faster to use an `ArrayList` simply because the memory is contiguous, which makes for less cache misses. What kind of insertions are these any ways? Insertions at the front of a LinkedList are fast but getting to an insertion point can take a lot of pointer indirections (and thus cache misses). Only way to really know which is faster is to benchmark though.

Comment: A viable Approach #4 may be to append to the ArrayList and sort it before performing retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to suggest a 4th approach: using `ArrayDeque` for the whole program. It has efficient insertion at the front and the back (possibly even faster then `LinkedList`) and search efficiency like `ArrayList`. `ArrayDeque` is an unfairly overlooked class in the Java Collections Framework, possibly because it was added later (Java 6, I think). It does *not*  implement the `List` interface, so you will have to write your program specifically for it.

Other than that, the only two valid answers to your question are

1. Do not worry about efficiency until you absolutely have to.
2. If and when you have to worry about efficiency, you will have to make your own measurements of what performs satisfactorily on *your* data in *your* environment. No one here can tell you.

Answer (score 5):

Since they both implement the same interface you can find this out for yourself by writing your code so that the constructor can be plugged in and test your code both ways. Benchmarking can be done with [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

You can plug in the constructor by using the [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) interface.

Depending on the nature of your problem you may find that using a [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on Frequencies of insert and retrieve operations. Here are the complexities:

- `ArrayList` -> Insertion in the beginning : **O(n)**
- `ArrayList` -> Retrieval based on index : **O(1)**
- `LinkedList` -> Insertion in the beginning : **O(1)**
- `LinkedList` -> Retrieval based on index : **O(i)** where i is number of elements to be scanned.

So, if you have more retrievals than insertions, go for `ArrayList`, if not, go for `LinkedList`.